# Is pry available in nitrous.io?

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry, nitrousio

I would like to use pry while debugging Ruby code in nitrous.io.  I updated RubyGems, but still cannot use it.  Is it available in nitrous.io?  How can I add it to my gems?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install it in the console by writing

```
gem install pry
```

or if you're trying to do rails

```
gem install pry-rails
```

because for me it worked perfectly, I had to close the console once and open a new one before it worked. I hope this helps